# Using SSD in PowerEdge T110 II

Tags: ssd

I would like to put two SSD drives into my T110 II and have two 3.5" bays free. I have read in various places that the T110 II doesn't support SSD natively, but I also have a PERC H200 controller with two conventional drives attached, and I have also read in a few places that this should work. All I need is a 2.5" to 3.5" adapter.

When I e-mailed Dell to ask for a part number they told me that I can't fit SSD into my configuration, so now I don't know where I stand. They have been unhelpful and unforthcoming, and won't give me the part number I've asked for. They just repeat that it isn't supported and so don't do it.

Please could someone settle this for me: can I put two SSD drives into my tower, in any configuration, but preferably RAID, and if so what adapter could I get to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Charles

[EDIT] As suggested by K7AAY, the result from WMIC:

Manufacturer: Dell Inc.

Model: PowerEdge T110 II

Name: MYSERVER

SystemType: x64-based PC

UPDATE: I purchased two Samsung V-NAND 860 QVO 2Tb SATA 6Gb/s drives and connected them to the two remaining cables in my server. Ctrl+C at boot-up to start the PERC H200 Config Utility and selected the drives in RAID 1 formation. It took nearly 24 hours to complete initialisation, but I discovered that I could actually use the drives during that time. They work perfectly, so yah boo sucks to Dell for bad (wrong) information. I have challenged them on this but they have not replied (no surprise there).

Comment: For future reference, this question is probably better suited for another SE network, maybe serverfault.com, since it's closer to a tech support request than a hardware rec. That said, you should be able to use SSDs with either the onboard controller or the H200; the only problem I see is that the H200 doesn't support TRIM, which *could* ([keyword](https://serverfault.com/questions/776564/what-is-the-current-state-2016-of-ssds-in-raid)) decrease SSD life and write performance.  I really wouldn't worry about it though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm tempted to give it a try as there seems to be more evidence that it will work than not. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 2 of the [spec sheet](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/T110_II_Spec_Sheet.pdf) specifies the Drive Bays as

> Cabled options available:
>   Up to six 2.5” SATA SSD or SAS drives or Up
>   to four 3.5” SAS, nearline SAS, or SATA drives

and the drive types

> 2.5” SATA SSD, SAS (10K)
>   3.5” SAS (15K), nearline SAS (7.2K), SATA (7.2K, 5.4K)

So I fail to understand why Dell spoke contrary to their own specifications. Perhaps another try may yield a tech there who's willing to actually read the spec sheet of your system? Or, [have you tried turning it off and then turning it back on again](https://www.cipher-it.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ITCrow.jpg)?

Comment: I see what you mean, the spec. sheet couldn't be clearer. Thanks. I added the result of WMIC to my original question as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I bought one of these for a similar situation: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B016498CK0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016498CK0)

It is a dual drive version, but there singles as well, and other brands too.

The rest of your question is more tech support, and off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had seen a few of those available in the UK as well so I think I will give it a try. Cheers.